# Remove space of the bullet when list-style-type: none is used

Tags: html, css, html-lists

This is my code:

```css
li.title {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0; 
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title">Title</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

As you see, there is a space before "Title" text where bullet is absent. I need to remove this space, by other words to align "Title" with left side of the list. How to do it when `list-style-type: none` is used?

Comment: `margin-left: -16px` try it on `li.title` class.

Comment: I'd rather go with `em` instead of `px` because that works regardless of `font-size`.

Comment: You are finding it difficult because this is semantically incorrect markup. The title of a list is not an item of the list, and does not belong as a `<li>`. Use a <label> or similar element before the list itself for a title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `list-style-position:inside`

```css
li.title {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title">Title</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That may yield unwanted results if any list item needs a line-break. To see it, replace `<li>two</li>` with `<li>two<br />linebreak here</li>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a negative `margin-left`:

```css
li.title {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -1em; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title">Title</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two<br />linebreak here</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you could also use a `transform`:

```css
li.title {
  list-style-type: none;
  transform: translateX(-1em);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title">Title</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two<br />linebreak here</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The reason above works is because the "space" you see in list items is due to `ul` having a padding left. To remove that space from one li item you need to give it a negative margin.